# Shopify to WordPress forwarding this same domain

Tags: wordpress, shopify

I have domain in ventraip australia hosting panel before i had point this domain in to my shopify account and now i want to change the the website shopify to WordPress so where I have to change the IP to open the site

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have hosting already set up to host your Wordpress website and files. You need to contact your domain registrar and ask them to help you change the DNS information and switch the domain over.